# mutex.Lock and defered mutex.Unock order

Tags: go, locking, defer-keyword

in golang, sync.Mutex Lock and Unlock are usaul operation,but what is the correct order of Lock and defer Unlock?

```
mu.Lock()
defer mu.Unlock()
```

or

```
defer mu.Unlock()
mu.Lock()
```

which is best?

Comment: Technically the order doesn't matter. Just that it's important to `Unlock`. Just that the first one is more logical and readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't matter.

Either way, `defer` causes `mu.Unlock()` to be executed when the current scope is exited (e.g. a function that returns).

The first method it's preferable, because it has a more natural ordering (lock, then unlock) for human readability.

Comment: Still, I would say the former is clearer as it captures the native flow of events: a resource is first acquired and *after that* its releasing is scheduled. The second variant puts that backwards. Also, I've never seen the second form in production code.

Comment: @kostix Yeah, I would prefer that, too.

Answer (score 2):

I see first variant more natural and easily readable. You may see as a lock gets acquired and at the same code piece it gets prepared to release:

```
mu.Lock()
defer mu.Unlock()
```

Anyway deferred function call will be executed later - at function exit.

Answer (score 0):

#### defer

> A defer statement defers the execution of a function until the surrounding function returns.
>
> The deferred call's arguments are evaluated immediately, but the function call is not executed until the surrounding function returns.

Both of your variants are identical because it doesn't matter where `defer`red functions are placed it will be executed after the surrounding function returns.

**Note** if you have several `defer`red functions it will be executed in reversed order accordingly to an order of `defer`s declaration.